# I dont know why 'Doub' isn't updating

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a program to count every time the dice
roll a double but my variable I'm trying to add to the `listbox` isn't updating and I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'declare vars
        Dim teal, red, doub As Integer
        Dim rand As New Random
        teal = rand.Next(6)
        red = rand.Next(6)
#Region "Clear"
Irrelevant stuff
#End Region
        'green dice
            irrelevant if statement
        'red dice
            irrelevant if statement
        'doubles
        **If red = teal Then
            doub = doub + 1
            output.Items.Clear()
            output.Items.Add("Doubles: " & doub)
        End If**
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the if statements about the dice part
there is nothing to influence the 'doub' variable
so thats why i put "irrelevant if statement"
also because stackoverflow said the post was mostly code

Comment: If *stackoverflow said the post was mostly code*, that means you need to add more actual text to explain the problem, not that you need to add irrelevant and useless noise to it. Regarding your question, what does the debugger show you when you step through the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `doub` variable is declared inside the button click handler so its scope is only within that procedure. That means it's getting released after every click. You need to have it outside your button click handler:

```
Dim doub As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Declare variables
    Dim teal As Integer
    Dim red As Integer
    Dim rand As New Random

    teal = rand.Next(6)
    red = rand.Next(6)

    Debug.Print(teal & "-" & red)

    ' Doubles
    If red = teal Then
        doub += 1
        Debug.Print("Doubles: " & doub)
    End If

End Sub
```

You can learn about variable scope in this link: [How to: Control the Scope of a Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/how-to-control-the-scope-of-a-variable)

Output (got a double on first try!):

```
4-4
Doubles: 1
1-5
0-5
5-0
2-2
Doubles: 2
3-0
```

This quick test shows another problem in your code: you can roll **0**, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. You should use `rand.Next(1,6)` instead, assuming you are trying to simulate a dice throw.